# How to get size of HttpServletRequest/response

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

How would I get the HttpServletRequest and response size ,using Java?.

I have tried something as follows but not sure this is the correct way to get the size of the request and response

```
public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response){
 Strig str_request = request.getInputStream().toString();
    char[] char_array_request = str_request.toCharArray();
    int requestSize = char_array_request.length;
}
```

Thanks in advance .....

Comment: Have you checked the "Content-Length" header in `request.getHeader("Content-Length")`?

Comment: 'Content-Length' gives only the size of the body ,Am I correct?. I want t get the size of request including the headers .

Comment: I suppose you can count all the bytes in the request input stream, but then you will need to read all bytes in it. I don't think it can be done otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the response header, you can read the Content-Length.

```
(Status-Line):HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Fri, 10 Mar 2015 14:00:00 GMT
Content-Length:728
```

Above is a sample.

Please read [further](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: I would like to get the size of request including the headers . I think 'Content-Length' gives only the size of the body ?

Comment: Furthermore, the Content-Length header is not always present. Consider "chunked" encoding for example...

Comment: There is no (HttpServletResponse) response.getHeader("Content-Length"); or response.getContentLength() So How would I get response Content-Length ?

Comment: I will request you to read the API first before commenting...https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment . getHeaders(...) methods HttpServletResponse are supported since Servlet 3.0. and I'm using 2.5

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to measure the total length of HTTP request and response messages using the standard Java EE API. You could:

- Put some kind of proxy in front of the app server that measures the message sizes;
- If you're using one of the open source servers you could modify it to provide the information to you in some way

Neither of these strategies is trivial.